# Enabling rsync with ssh keygen and no password

Tags: ssh-keys

I would like to setup a rsync a folder inside /etc, I followed this link http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Use-RSA-Key-for-SSH-Authentication-38599.shtml and created one user added in visudo and then with ssh keygen, transferred the public key to remote machine, but still its asking for password.

Any other way would be recommended.

Thanks.

Comment: show something. like the users you created, the rsync command, your sshd cinfig, ...

Comment: My rsync is as follows - /usr/bin/rsync -azPp --rsh='ssh -p 8774' --exclude='sip_trunk.conf' --exclude='extensions_global.conf' --exclude='iax_trunk.conf' /etc/asterisk gopal@xx.xx.xx.xx:/etc/

Comment: what does `ssh -p 8664 gopal@10.10.10.81` do?

Comment: actually its 8774 it will communicate my other server.

Answer (score 2):

The link that you gave us is right, but there is something that they miss. In the backup-server you must change the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config, uncomment this line

`AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys`

and your no password access should be working. In resume:

***Client*** (where you have yours original files)

In a terminal write:

`$ ssh-keygen -t rsa`

this create the id_rsa.pub file in /home/USER/.ssh/

***Server*** (where you will backup yours files)

modify the ssh_config file:

`#nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

and uncomment the line

`AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys`

and now just copy the content of `.ssh/id_rsa.pub`(Client) at the end of `.ssh/authorized_keys`(Server) and the no-password will be working(to connect from *Client* to *Server*). Maybe you need to restart your ssh server with

`/etc/init.d/ssh restart`

To make your rsync just do (you don't gave us too much information, but I suppose this)

`rsync -az --delete --progress /etc/ server:destinationFolder/`

this will make a backup of */etc/* in the *Client* to *destinationFolder/* in the *Server*, show you the progress of the backup, will delete the file that are not in the source and will send compress the files. The access permissions to the `.ssh/` directory in the *Server* must be 700, i.e: `chmod -R 700 .ssh/`

Possible errors:

1."*Agent admitted failure using the key*"

Sol: ***After*** you disconnect from the server (logged with the password) you must type in your client terminal `ssh-add`